# SQL Server Zero Values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am pretty green at this stuff and have a problem with what I thought was a simple select and calculate SQL Formula.

The issue being is that in my table I have a lot of zero values, sound's wierd I know but this is how it is.

The formula is to calculate a percentage marin based on two columns these being Total and Costs, whilst my simple formula works if there's a value, when theres a zero value absolutely nothing works.

The formula I am using is this ((Total-Costs)/Total)*100

Can anyone advise this greenhorn how to overcome the zero value issue?

Comment: Please post the actual query you ran and the errors it threw to save us time figuring out what the problem is. Thank you!

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: You should post more informations about your schema and the meaning of _"absolutely nothing works"_. Try to show some sample records, do you also have `NULL` values?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
SELECT COALESCE((Total- Costs / NULLIF(Total,0))*100, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If Total has a 0 in it, you'll get a divide by zero error. You must catch these using a CASE statement, like so

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN Total = 0 then 0 else ((Total-Costs)/Total)*100 END AS Percentage
FROM
Tbl
```